# D-Link DNS-323 NAS firmware update

Tags: nas

I've got a D-Link DNS-323 NAS enclosure holding a bunch of multimedia files that I've (possibly stupidly) just updated the firmware on, from 1.03 to 1.08.

The updater indicated it applied the firmware patch successfully, but after rebooting it I can no longer get into it via the web interface, either via the static IP I had assigned it before the update, or by any of the DHCP-assigned addresses that I can see are currently assigned by my router.

The unit just sits there, with the drives (2x512 set up as RAID-1) thrashing away seemingly forever...

So, my question - has anyone had a similar experience with one of these units? Any advice etc? I've googled all I could for it, and can't find anything useful.

Comment: Update: the disk thrashing has now stopped, so I just did a port scan, and these ports are open:
    
    139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
    445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
    515/tcp  open  printer
    3689/tcp open  rendezvous

Sure enough, I can now browse the filesystem and can see all files, so I should at least be able to copy all the data. However, no port 80 for the web interface...

Comment: no ssh or telnet to check what's going on?

Comment: Is there a "Reset" button on the thing anywhere? That might help. It might be a good idea to back it up first, though. Also, packet-sniffing it's boot activity might be useful (use wireshark).

Comment: I managed to telnet in after copying the fun_plug tools into the drive's root via the samba share & rebooting... Poking around indicates that the thing is running normally, apart from the daemon that serves the admin webpages... I'm going to factory reset it now. Annoying...

Comment: Yep, that's sorted it, although I now have to reconfigure everything... Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

FYI - If anyone stumbles across this, I think the problem (the admin webapp daemon not starting after upgrading) was caused by the config format changing from a text format to a binary one in one of the firmware releases between 1.03 & 1.08...

A reset to factory config shold sort it out - there's a pinhole button on the back next to the LAN port - push that in for 10 seconds or so while the device is running.